# Custom Column with Origin of Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I have a power query with 14 tables from 14 sheets. The columns on each table vary. Some have columns unique to a sheet. They all share about 10 columns, but the order varies.

How can I go about adding a custom column to show either the sheet origin or table origin?

(I strategically named the tables/sheets to each table on sheet is as follows `Table Name = Sheet Name`). I am new to power-query, and by new, I mean I built my first one today.

I tried a custom column with formula:
`Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Source{[Item="Report",Kind="Sheet"]}[Name])` which does not work as seen below.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

All tables you want to bind together in your query doesn't have necessary the same structure (column names). Here a solution for this case.
You have to write a custom M-Code. Use as first step the **Excel.CurrentWorkbook** function.

Here the M-Code you can put in your Editor (the query Name is in my example "OutputTable" -> to be replaced in the code below!):

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
    // Filter out the table (= your Query Name) which will result as output
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Name] <> "OutputTable")),

    // Bring the table name as 1st column
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),

    // Rename the "Name" column to prevent conflict with next steps
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Name", "TableName"}}),

    // Find out all column names present in Content tables 
    #"all table column name" = List.Accumulate(#"Renamed Columns"[Content], {}, (state, current) => List.Union({state, Table.ColumnNames(current)})),

    // Dynamically expand all columns
    #"Expanded {0}" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Content", #"all table column name")
in
    #"Expanded {0}"
```

The step *#"all table column name"* is inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44443167) answer on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Table structures are not the same. Count of columns vary

Comment: ok, I've updated the script to take it in account

Comment: Can test this afternoon